# Why is there no translation for the language 'en_US'?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

Here is my config.ini

```
resources.locale.default = "en"
resources.translate.adapter = "gettext"
resources.translate.data = APPLICATION_PATH "/../languages/"
resources.translate.option.scan = "directory"
resources.translate.registry_key = "Zend_Translate"
resources.translate.disableNotices = true
resources.translate.default = en
```

And my languages are structured like in the manual:

```
application/
languages/
-- en/
---- LC_MESSAGES/
------ default.po
-- se/
---- LC_MESSAGES/
------ default.po
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

This happens when your translation file for en_US contains only original strings. You need to translate at least one string from original to translated version, compile your *.po to *.mo  again, and then it'll start working. If not, rename default.mo to messages.mo, or try even renaming the directory en to en_US.